# Como acessar o SDCARD no Android 4.4(API 19)

Tags: java, android

Atualmente tenho um aplicativo rodando em 100 celulares com android 2.3(estabelecido pelo cliente), porém estão trocando os celulares para 4.4 e utilizo o `sd card` para armazenar e depois exibir como listagem de produtos.

O problema é no Android 4.4 eu não consigo criar pastas dentro do `sd card`, atualmente utilizo o seguinte código para verificação e criação da pasta.

```
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    {
        
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "imagem");
        file.mkdirs();
        

        if (file.isDirectory())

        {
         //metodos que fazem pesquisa de imagens omitidos

        }
```

caminho retornado pelos metodos acima no Android 2.3:

> /mnt/sdcard/imagem

caminho retornado pelos metodos acima no Android 4.4 ele lista como "Criado" porém não cria:

> /storage/emulated/0/imagem

Olhei a [documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29) e não obtive resultados, mudou a forma de acesso entre as versões?

O `AndroidManifest.xml` já está com permissão para ler e escrever no sdcard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Os Smartphones mais recentes podem ter [mais de um](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/traditional.html#multiple-external-storage-devices) *External Storage*. Além do *sdcard* têm um interno. O *path* retornado por `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` refere-se ao *dispositivo de armazenamento externo primário* que, nestes casos, é o interno.

A partir da versão 19 (Android 4.4) a classe *Context* disponibiliza o método [getExternalFilesDirs()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDirs%28java.lang.String%29) que retorna um `File[]` com os *paths* para todos os directórios específicos à aplicação, de todos os dispositivos de armazenamento externos.

O primeiro caminho devolvido no *array* é o mesmo que o retornado por [getExternalFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29).

Para obter os caminhos onde guardar dados relativos à aplicação, tal como é referido na [documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29), devem ser usados os métodos atrás referidos e não `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Comment: eu posso usar em versões anteriores também?

Comment: Nesse caso use  [ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getExternalFilesDirs%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%29) que funciona em todas as versões.

Comment: Criei  um projeto teste funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score -1):

Adicione no AndroidManifest.xml

Depois vai dispositivo Android em: Configurações -> Apps -> Avançado -> Gerenciamento de Permissão-> Arquivos e Mídia  -> Seu App -> Permitir gerenciamento de todos os arquivos

Enjoy and Test your code again!!!