# Ler arquivo XML só com um Nodo Pai

Tags: android, xml, dom

Eu necessito de importar um arquivo XML que possui a seguinte estrutura:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Registos>3</Registos>

<Socios>

    <id>1</id>
    <nome>Paulo</nome>
    <email>paulo@mail.com</email>

    <id>2</id>
    <nome>Vitor</nome>
    <email>vitor@mail.com</email>

    <id>3</id>
    <nome>Rute</nome>
    <email>rute@mail.com</email>

</Socios>
```

Eu estou a utilizar o DOM para ler o arquivo mas o meu problema é que ele só possui um Nodo Pai

```xml
<Socios>...</Socios>
```

Alguém me pode ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este seu XML tem um problema básico, que é possuir mais de um tag raiz (`<Registos />` e `<Socios />`), tornando-o um XML não válido. Como não é um formato válido você não conseguirá lê-lo com DOM, pois ele espera um XML válido, então um erro parecido com este deve ocorrer:

```
[Fatal Error] :4:2: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
    lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 2; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

O correto é você já esperar um XML bem formado, como o sugerido no final desta resposta. Caso isto esteja além do que você pode fazer, se é entregue por alguma outra aplicação que não você não detém, como em uma integração com terceiros, então você terá que contornar isto ajustado o XML recebido. A sugestão é formar um XML válido a partir do que recebe, incluindo um tag raiz qualquer. Usarei `<Data />` como exemplo.

Nosso código para transformar o XML em um formato válido será mais ou menos assim:

```java
private static final String DATA_ROOT_START = "<Data>";
private static final byte[] DATA_ROOT_START_BYTES = DATA_ROOT_START.getBytes();
private static final String DATA_ROOT_END = "</Data>";
private static final byte[] DATA_ROOT_END_BYTES = DATA_ROOT_END.getBytes();
private static final String XML_HEADER = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
private static final byte[] XML_HEADER_BYTES = XML_HEADER.getBytes();
private static final int XML_HEADER_LENGTH = XML_HEADER.length();

public InputStream fixXML(final InputStream is) throws Exception {
    try (final InputStream startIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(DATA_ROOT_START_BYTES);
            final InputStream headerIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(XML_HEADER_BYTES);
            final InputStream endIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(DATA_ROOT_END_BYTES)) {
        is.skip(XML_HEADER_LENGTH);
        final List<InputStream> streams = Arrays.asList(headerIS, startIS, is, endIS);
        return new SequenceInputStream(Collections.enumeration(streams));
    }
}
```

Esse cara recupera o `InputStream` do conteúdo do seu XML, sem o cabeçalho. incluindo o tag raiz que escolhemos e também o cabeçalho (este não é obrigatório em determinados casos).

Depois de corrigido poderemos ler o XML, algo assim:

```
final AssetManager manager = getAssets();
final InputStream is = manager.open("socios.xml");
final InputStream fixedXMLIS = fixXML(is);

final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
final DocumentBuilder db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
final InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(fixedXMLIS);
final Document document = db.parse(inputSource);

final NodeList socios = document.getElementsByTagName("Socios");
final int sociosSize = socios.getLength();
for (int i = 0; i < sociosSize; i++) {
    final Node socio = socios.item(i);
    final NodeList socioChilds = socio.getChildNodes();
    final int socioChildsSize = socioChilds.getLength();
    for (int j = 0; j < socioChildsSize; j++) {
        final Node e = socioChilds.item(j);
        Log.d("XMLFIXSample", e.getTextContent().trim());
    }
}
```

Isto irá gerar algo assim:

```
I/XMLFIXSample(N): 1
I/XMLFIXSample(N): Paulo
I/XMLFIXSample(N): paulo@mail.com
I/XMLFIXSample(N): 2
I/XMLFIXSample(N): Vitor
I/XMLFIXSample(N): vitor@mail.com
I/XMLFIXSample(N): 3
I/XMLFIXSample(N): Rute
I/XMLFIXSample(N): rute@mail.com
```

Depois disto você usa os valores conforme sua necessidade, preenchendo diretamente algum campo na tela, entidade, etc.

Obs.: este código é um exemplo que tranforma o XML em um formato válido, adapte-o e melhore-o conforme suas necessidades, perceba que usa coisas do Java7, então se quiser usar assim, configure corretamente o `target` para compilar para uma versão que o Android suporte ;)

Obs2.: não sei se é você que está gerando este XML, mas se for, considere colocá-lo em um formato válido, com apenas um nó raiz, algo assim:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    <Registos>3</Registos>

    <Socios>
        <id>1</id>
        <nome>Paulo</nome>
        <email>paulo@mail.com</email>

        <id>2</id>
        <nome>Vitor</nome>
        <email>vitor@mail.com</email>

        <id>3</id>
        <nome>Rute</nome>
        <email>rute@mail.com</email>
    </Socios>
</Data>
```

Outra coisa que você pode fazer é ter um tag raiz para os dados do sócio, algo assim:

```xml
<Socio>
    <id>1</id>
    <nome>Paulo</nome>
    <email>paulo@mail.com</email>
</Socio>
```

Gerando este resultado final:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    <Registos>3</Registos>

    <Socios>
        <Socio>
            <id>1</id>
            <nome>Paulo</nome>
            <email>paulo@mail.com</email>
        </Socio>

        <Socio>
            <id>2</id>
            <nome>Vitor</nome>
            <email>vitor@mail.com</email>
        </Socio>

        <Socio>
            <id>3</id>
            <nome>Rute</nome>
            <email>rute@mail.com</email>
        </Socio>
    </Socios>
</Data>
```

Isto tornaria ainda mais simples a forma de trabalhar com o XML

Comment: Bruno César, obrigado pela resposta. O meu arquivo "socios.xml" está no SDCard0, mas não estou a conseguir com que a linha "final InputStream is = manager.open(arquivoXML );" encontre o arquivo XML. Eu possuo a permissão de leitura "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" e a seguinte configuração: File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File arquivoXML = new File(SDCardRoot, "socios.xml"); Consegue perceber o que me está a falha?

Comment: @VitorMendanha aí já é outra coisa, talvez seja melhor você fazer outra pergunta, caso necessita. Antes pesquise aqui mesmo no SOpt sobre o tema, há algumas perguntas, como [esta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70177)

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema: Substitui a linha "final InputStream is = manager.open("socios.xml");" por "InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(arquivoXML ));".

Comment: @VitorMendanha é isso aí :)

Answer (score 1):

Bom Vítor não sou um expert em XML , mas em seu arquivo falta a raiz uma tag para agrupar todas as outras. exemplo [Aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/).
E, pela lógica, todos os nodes terão apenas 1 parent, entretanto o contrato é possível ( um node pai ter vários filhos)

Dica: Agrupe  as tags sócios  e  registros dentro de uma raiz

E [neste link](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_nodes_get.asp) pode se encontrar algo que te ajude sobre a leitura do valor dos nós

Comment: Bill Silva, obrigado pela resposta. Pelo que percebo, não vai ser fácil resolver o meu problema, porque tenho de ler vários arquivos diferentes...