# mkdir no android não funciona

Tags: android

Estou tentando criar uma pasta no Android para salvar as fotos dos comprovantes, mas não estou tendo sucesso. Já dei permissão no Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="<meu.package>">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

e, de acordo com as novas regras do Android 7.0, estou solicitando essas permissões em tempo de execução.

O código esta assim:

```
 private void CriaPasta() {
        pasta = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Android/data/" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/comprovantes/";
        File folder = new File(pasta);

        if (!folder.exists()) {
            if (!folder.mkdir()) ;
            Toast.makeText(this, pasta + " não pode ser criada.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    CriaPasta();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Aqui no metodo UpdateView desta activity eu verifico se já tenho permissão e tento criar a pasta caso ela não exista. Aqui o fluxo segue direto para a rotina CriaPasta porque essa permissão já foi pedida na entrada principal do programa.

```
    private void UpdateView() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        } else {
            CriaPasta();
        }
    }
```

Porém na rotina CriaPasta a mensagem dizendo que a pasta não pode ser criada ocorre todas as vezes.

Esse é parte do arquivo build.gradle.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "<meu.package>"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
```

Parece ter a ver com essa versão, porque em outros aplicativos meus a criação de pastas semelhantes ocorre normalmente no mesmo aparelho.

Aliás, quando instalo os outros aplicativos o Android cria a pasta emulated/0/Android/data/ automaticamente e nesse aplicativo isso não acontece.

Comment: A única razão que encontro para não conseguir é que o directório não esteja acessível. Pode verificar utilizando [getExternalStorageState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageState()). De qualquer forma, a partir da versão 19 (Android 4.4) não deve utilizar esse método. Ao lidar com o *External Storage* tenha presente o que é dito nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70277/2541).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há um método mais natural para alcançar o diretório em que está tentando criar suas pastas:

#### Context.getExternalFilesDir(@Nullable String type)

> Retorna o caminho absoluto para o diretório no dispositivo de armazenamento primário compartilhado/externo onde o aplicativo pode colocar
> arquivos persistentes de sua propriedade. Esses arquivos são internos
> aos aplicativos e normalmente não são visíveis para o usuário como
> mídia.

Esse método retorna um `File` apontando para */memóriaInterna/Android/data/nome.do.pacote/files*

Então, tente substituir dessa forma:

```
private void CriaPasta() {
    File pasta = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "comprovantes");
    /*
       /memóriaInterna/Android/data/nome.do.pacote/files/comprovantes
    */
    if (!pasta.exists()) {
        if (!pasta.mkdirs()) { // <- mkdirs()
            Toast.makeText(this, pasta + " não pode ser criada.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Perceba que usei `mkdirs()` que cria a pasta, incluindo qualquer diretório pai necessário, mas inexistente.

Comment: Perfeito Lennoard. Funcionou corretamente.